# CRM2011 - Update account money value - working for one field - but not other field

Tags: c#, crm

This is a bit of a longshot but here goes...

I am currently working on a project that interfaces with Microsoft CRM 2011 via its XRMServices.

My problem is that certain money (a.k.a Currency) values are updated in the [AccountBase] table whilst others are not. The [revenue] field is updated, but the [aging30] value is not. Both of these field share the same major properties:

1. The are both of Type Currency
2. They are both default fields.
3. They both dont seem to have any database constraints on them.
   !!  [aging30] seems to be read only however !!

What could be causing this despite the fact that the field might be read only? I thought that I might have something to-do with the field level security or user security, but that does not seem to be it. I have sufficient rights on the system and the field properties are not set to disable such actions.
The only other thing I could think of is that it might be a workflow that is prohibiting me from updating this value, but once again I could not see anything in the system that seems related to this point. After running the code below the entity is revenue value is updated and is visible in dbo.AccountBase, but the [aging30] field is not. No exception is generated by the XRM web service.

**Figure 1 - Retrieving the account**

```
 public Entity GetByAccountCode(string accountCode, bool allColumns = false)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountCode))
            return default(Entity);
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("account");
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(allColumns);
        query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();

        query.Criteria.AddCondition("accountnumber", ConditionOperator.Equal, accountCode);

        EntityCollection results = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
        if (results.Entities.Count == 0)
            return default(Entity);
        if (results.Entities.Count > 1)
            throw new DuplicateRecordsOnAccountCodeException(accountCode, "Duplicate records on AccountCode found"); // needs to be changed appropriatly

        return results[0] as Entity;

    }
```

Figure 2 - Updating the account**

```
 account.Attributes["revenue"] = new Money((decimal)100m); // This value is updated
 account.Attributes["aging30"] = new Money((decimal)200m); // This value is not
 _service.Update(entity);
```

Comment: Possibly a plugin? Maybe hook up Sql Server Profiler and see what is happening under the covers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151365.aspx) this field (aging30) is a platform and valid only for read.